# Need assistance manipulating data from MySQL with data from DataTable

Tags: jquery, mysql, datatables

Is it possible to update a mysql table (displayed with DataTables) with foreign keys?
For example, I have two tables:

```
`table1`(`id`, `type`, `description`);
`table2`(`id`, `name`);
```

Let's say the tables are populated with:

```
[1, 1, 'description 1']
```

and

```
[1, 'type 1'],
[2, 'type 2']
```

My `table1`.`type` field is an integer foreign key for Table2's `id` field. I can run a select query:

```
SELECT `table1`.`id`, `table2`.`name`, `table1`.`description`
FROM `table1`
LEFT JOIN `table2` ON
`table1`.`type` = `table2`.`id`;
```

Then, display it with DataTables to produce a table containing the following fields: `table1`.`id`, `table2`.`name`, `table1`.`description`

I can read the data from the datatable with:

```
var $data = $('#myTable').DataTable();
var $row = $data.rows().data();
```

I want to update the foreign key with a new id.

My first thought was to do a MySQL UPDATE but this will error out because `name` doesn't exist in `table1` (only a foreign key reference to `table2`.`id`)

How would I update the foreign key reference if the returned values from  $data.rows().data() displays the string `name` field instead of integer `id` from `table2` (from the SELECT statement mentioned earlier)?

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/ns6zahpc/1/

EDIT: Is there a way to display both the integer id value and the string name value in the same cell?

Comment: have you tried adding in your select query the id of the foreign key? how do you update the `type` column of table1?

Comment: @dunli I've figured out the solution to my problem using an inner SELECT statement:

UPDATE table1 SET `type` = (
    SELECT id FROM table2
    WHERE name = 'type 2'
)
WHERE table1.id = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want;

```
UPDATE table1 SET `type` = 'your_value' WHERE `type` IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM table2
    WHERE name = 'some_name_value'
);
```

Comment: I'll give this a try. I kept looking for some kind of solution in javascript and that tunnel vision got the best of me.

Comment: Just trying to break down that query, but the inner SELECT will return an ID from table2. So now,

     UPDATE table1 SET `type` = `?` WHERE `type` IN (%table2.id%)

would still work?

Would: 

    UPDATE table1 SET `type` = (SELECT `id` FROM table2 WHERE `type` = (?)) WHERE table1.id = (%selector%)

be more appropriate?

Comment: I think i'm on the right track now. Thanks @Kostas Mitsarakis

Comment: You can try some variations depending on your data. I 'm glad that i helped you!